# How to display facebook details in our android app with login?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have two edittexts..One for username and other for password ..and also a button ..
I am using facebook-sdk-android from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

What i want is onclick of button I want to show *facebook details* of that user (User will type facebook credentials) I want user shud not go anywhere out of my app ...I even dont want the facebook login screen which i get now ..

---

2) question is how to display the user details in my android app in particular format example gridview or listview??

or i want to achieve this login with facebook button..Onclick of that button there wud be a popup of facebook login screen..

[Image Login](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&tbo=d&biw=1024&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbnid=jSaqtM-tBezs0M%3a&imgrefurl=http://quickblox.com/developers/SuperSample_%28Map_Chat_code_sample%29_Android&docid=F65ONe8Mql4dyM&imgurl=http://quickblox.com/developers/images/5/58/SuperSample-android-login-fb1.png&w=320&h=480&ei=r6P2UPa-AcSUrgemooGoCQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=709&vpy=84&dur=1964&hovh=275&hovw=183&tx=65&ty=113&sig=117413978145150939804&page=1&tbnh=134&tbnw=89&start=0&ndsp=30&ved=1t:429,r:6,s:0,i:99)

Comment: user can not login to facebook using your app / and / without a webview

Comment: thanks @SherifelKhatib for reply .. i dun want to login to facebook using my app instead i want to login into my app using facebook credentials ..then i will save that user accordingly..

Comment: if you will use facebook api means will get the credentials like username, dateofbirth, and list of friends.. and email address.. but you wont get password..

Comment: thanks @itsrajesh4uguys but i really dont need password ...i just wana show welcome XYZ(XYZ wud be username in facebook)in next page of my app rather it wud be homescreen..

Comment: you can get those things easily.. did you tried any samples ?

Comment: yeah i did a few of them but unsucessful.. have u seen that image in my question ?? i wanna have like that ..just a pop-up after click on login with facebook button..Hope u get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Social Plugins is what you are looking for:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Registration details automatically populated:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Login Button:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

To get more information out of the user you would then have to go all the way and create a facebook application. Check the relative documentation for that.

Comment: Please vote if this was of help and mark as answer if it did what you were looking for - which is what i believe you asked for.